# What is the difference between 'Thread of instruction' and 'Thread of control'?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I read the above terms used with implied difference in their meaning, but I couldn't figure out where I read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that 'thread of instruction' refers to just code and the way it flows round the functions, procedures, loops and conditionals. 'Thread of control' refers to execution by kernel thread with its own program counter/stack.  One 'thread of instruction' can have many 'threads of control' executing its code.

Comment: @MitchWheat - any thread of instruction that calls join() or any thread that is join()ed with.  It's a sword of Damocles thing..